# Error code -10810 when calling "open" from applescript

Tags: shell, applescript

I'm trying to use AppleScript to modify some app settings. The code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo '
 tell application "Finder"
   tell disk "'$1'"
       open
       set current view of container window to icon view
       ...
       close
   end tell
end tell
' | osascript
```

However, I keep on getting a -10810 error code when applescript hits "open" ("64:68: execution error: An error of type -10810 has occurred. (-10810)"). I've done some googling and all I got was "reboot and wait, it sometimes magically starts working" (it didn't).

The machine is running Mac OS Server 10.6. I though it perhaps might be some permissions issue, but running the command as root returns the same error.

**Update**: Solved (well, more or less :-) ). The thing is that "open" needs a UI. And the problem was that I was using ssh to run the script (which I didn't mention here, because I didn't think it was relevant). So there was no UI. It works when I log in using VNC first.

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need (and probably shouldn't have) a `#!/bin/sh` line at the beginning. You're not running this via `sh`, you're running it via applescript.

Comment: He is running it as a shell command.  Look closer.  He's passing in an argument via the command line.  The problem of checking whether someone is logged in (and you can run Applescript) is a tricky one a lot of people forget about.  If you want to test to ensure someone is logged in you can run the shell command "users" which lists currently logged in users.  Obviously this will not return any user if no-one is logged in.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post your solution as an answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (well, more or less :-) ).

The thing is that "open" needs a UI. And the problem was that I was using ssh to run the script (which I didn't mention here, because I didn't think it was relevant). So there was no UI. It works when I log in using VNC first.